# load 1 random image (maybe 10 images) in 1 div tag

Tags: jquery, image, random

I am not a true programmer and need some help.
I need  a script that inserts a div tag and within that div tag have a random image load (from a list of 10) when the page laods from an external js file.

I searched and searched and tried different ways but really need help.

Thanks

Comment: you need to post your code here or do better search with `javascript insert random image`

Answer (score 1):

The solution below uses jQuery, but it can be achieved without it in a simple way

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  function randomInt(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
  }

  var imageUrls = [
    "https://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery3/1.sm.png",
    "https://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery3/2.sm.png",
    "https://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery3/3.sm.png"
  ];

  var randomImage = imageUrls[randomInt(0, imageUrls.length - 1)];

  $(".container").append("<img alt='" + randomImage + "' src='" + randomImage + "'</>");


});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
</div>
```

---

### Update - Same answer inside a complete HTML valid page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
    </script>    
    <script type="text/javascript">


        /**
        * Loads a random number
        */
        function randomInt(min, max) {
            return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
        }

        // List of urls
        var imageUrls = [
            "https://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery3/1.sm.png",
            "https://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery3/2.sm.png",
            "https://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery3/3.sm.png"
        ];

        function loadRandomImage() {
            var randomImage = imageUrls[randomInt(0, imageUrls.length - 1)];
            $(".container").append(
                    "<img alt='" + randomImage + "' src='" + randomImage + "'</>");
        }

        // This function executes when the DOM is ready, 
        // e.g., when the entire page is loaded
        $(document).ready(function() {
            loadRandomImage()
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: So I place the $(document) portion into the script tags in the head of te doc? and the  second part into body?

Comment: I don't get your question. I updated my answer to show you a very straightforward way to include the code in a simple HTML page. Maybe you should post *your* HTML code to see where you still have doubts?

Comment: @AntoineScotto The first part is the javascript. It either needs to be between the `<script></script>` tags or in an external JS file being referenced by the page. The second part is the HTML which belongs somewhere between the `<body></body>` tags.

Comment: Read the updated answer. It has all the segments in the right place. Snippet is just that, a snippet, Stackoverflows knows where to place them.

Comment: Thanks! I will try this and see

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to throw in vanilla JS answer as well.

```
<style>
    #show-picture {
        display: block; 
        margin: 20px; 
        height: 400px; 
        width: 400px; 
        box-shadow: 0 0 12px rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
        background-size: cover; 
        background-position: center; 
    }
</style>

<div id="show-picture"></div>

<script>
    const images = [
        'https://picsum.photos/400/400?image=600',
        'https://picsum.photos/400/400?image=601',
        'https://picsum.photos/400/400?image=602',
        'https://picsum.photos/400/400?image=603',
        'https://picsum.photos/400/400?image=604',
        'https://picsum.photos/400/400?image=605',
        'https://picsum.photos/400/400?image=606',
        'https://picsum.photos/400/400?image=607',
        'https://picsum.photos/400/400?image=608',
        'https://picsum.photos/400/400?image=609',
    ]

    // get random image
    const random_number = Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length); 
    const image = images[random_number]; 

    // get div and set background-image CSS to be our random image
    const show_picture = document.getElementById('show-picture');
    show_picture.style.backgroundImage = `url(${image})`; 
</script>
```